# Isn't the Reminders app on iPad allowing you to trigger an alarm when you leave a location?

Tags: ipad, applications

Isn't Reminders app on iPad allowing you to trigger an alarm when you leave a location ?

I can only find the option to set the time. I do have a 3G version of the iPad so it does have the GPS chip which in theory should make this feature as beneficial as on an iPhone with GPS and a data connection.

Comment: Does your iPad have a GPS chip?

Comment: @bmike It is the 3G model. How do I know if it has the GPS ?

Comment: The 3G models have the GPS chips added so they can geolocate much better than the WiFi only iPads and iPod touch. I'm a little surprised that didn't make the cut for the shipping version of reminders. I could see leaving 3GS out - but iPad 2 and iPad (1?) are pretty recent and have CPU and battery power to support an extra process from where I see things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be currently available for the iPhone 4 and 4s only. Give this page a look. Several frustrated commenters.
[Macworld Review](http://www.macworld.com/article/162991/2011/10/up_close_with_ios_5_reminders.html)

Comment: Yup. Apple may have added this limitation as a differentiation feature, or they may just be testing it on the 4S until they are sure that it works reliably. (My guess is the former, but I don't know for sure.)